# How to make android studio stop checking for 'what's new assistant version'?

Tags: android, android-studio

In android studio Electric Eel, or recent versions, it checks for 'what's new assistant version' at the startup. I do not think its necessary and I do not want it to check for any such that is not necessary. I do not want such because it keeps checking and with an active and okay internet connection it does not finish checking soon, so gradle project sync stays in progress.
So how do I stop it and make android studio startup faster?

[image]